# I'd like to make the ultimate bootable USB with several distributions on it. How?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, live-usb, clonezilla

I have a USB key attached to my keyfob, and I'd like to turn it into a toolbox where I have bootable images on it (DBAN, Clonezilla, Kali, Ubuntu...)

Is there a way to have all these images on the stick, and have a GRUB when I boot off it to select which distribution to launch? I would also like to make it easy to upgrade the various distributions independently.

I suspect some kind of multiboot, but don't know if that's the right way to go or where to start.